# how do I loop through a set of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

how do I loop through a set of records from a select?

Here is my stored procedure query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[procedure_rastavljanjeOtpremnica] (@radniNalogID INT) AS 
DECLARE @bool BIT = 0
IF(@bool = 'FALSE')
BEGIN
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY S.PuniNaziv) AS num_row, S.PuniNaziv, a.KolicinaMjeracaIElektronike FROM ArtikliUslugeNaloga a
INNER JOIN SifreArtikala S ON S.Id = a.Artikal1Id 
INNER JOIN UslugeNaloga ON UslugeNaloga.Id = a.UslugeNalogaId
WHERE a.RobaSkart = @bool AND UslugeNaloga.RadniNalogID = @radniNalogID
END
```

The result is:

```
now_row  PuniNaziv                                   Kolicina
1        Komunik internet jed s ugrađ WIFi sensoNET   3 
2        Ventil tahret DN15 (1/2")                    5 
3        Vodokotlić Geberit                           1
```

So what I need to do is to add another column that will print KOM for every row,
This is the result that I am looking for:

```
  now_row      PuniNaziv                                Kolicina   Jedinia mjere
    1        Komunik internet jed s ugrađ WIFi sensoNET   3         Kom
    2        Ventil tahret DN15 (1/2")                    5         Kom
    3        Vodokotlić Geberit                           1         Kom
```

Can anyone give me idea how to do this

Comment: `IF(@bool = 'FALSE')` should be `IF(@bool = 0)`

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to "loop".  Just add the column to your query:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY S.PuniNaziv) AS num_row, 
       S.PuniNaziv, a.KolicinaMjeracaIElektronike,
       'Kom' as Jedinia_mjere
FROM ArtikliUslugeNaloga a JOIN
     SifreArtikala S
     ON S.Id = a.Artikal1Id JOIN
     UslugeNaloga
      ON UslugeNaloga.Id = a.UslugeNalogaId
WHERE a.RobaSkart = @bool AND
      UslugeNaloga.RadniNalogID = @radniNalogID;
```

Note:  If you want to ensure that the rows are returned in the order specified by `num_row`, you should add `ORDER BY num_row` to the query.

Comment: Ohhh that was so easy I was looking the wrong way to do this :/ Thank you so much :)